# sed statement to change/modify CSV separators and delimiters

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sed

I have some CSV files which contains comma seperated values and some of the column values can contain characters like `,.<>!/\;&`

I am trying to convert the CSV to be a comma separated, quote enclosed CSV

Example Data:

```
DateCreated,DateModified,SKU,Name,Category,Description,Url,OriginalUrl,Image,Image50,Image100,Image120,Image200,Image300,Image400,Price,Brand,ModelNumber
2012-10-19 10:52:50,2013-06-11 02:07:16,34,Austral Foldaway 45 Rotary Clothesline,Home & Garden > Household Supplies > Laundry Supplies > Drying Racks & Hangers,"Watch the Product Video            Plenty of Space to Hang a Family Wash  Austral's Foldaway 45 rotary clothesline is a folding head rotary clothes hoist beautifully finished in either Beige or Heritage Green.  Even though the Foldaway 45 is compact, you still get a large 45 metres of line space, big enough for a full family wash.  If you want the advantage of a rotary hoist, but dont want to lose your yard, then the Austral Foldaway 45 is the clothesline for you.&nbsp;  Installation Note:&nbsp;A core hole is only required when installing into existing concrete, e.g. a pathway. Not required in the ground(grass/soil).  To watch video on YouTube, click the following link:&nbsp;Austral Foldaway 45 Rotary Clothesline      &nbsp;            //           Customer Video Reviews  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",https://track.commissionfactory.com.au/p/10604/1718695,http://www.lifestyleclotheslines.com.au/austral-foldaway-45-rotary-clothesline/,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695.jpg,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@50x50.jpg,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@100x100.jpg,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@120x120.jpg,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@200x200.jpg,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@300x300.jpg,http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@400x400.jpg,309.9000 AUD,Austral,FA45GR
```

And the output I'm trying to achieve is

```
"DateCreated","DateModified","SKU","Name","Category","Description","Url","OriginalUrl","Image","Image50","Image100","Image120","Image200","Image300","Image400","Price","Brand","ModelNumber"
"2012-10-19 10:52:50","2013-06-11 02:07:16","34","Austral Foldaway 45 Rotary Clothesline","Home & Garden > Household Supplies > Laundry Supplies > Drying Racks & Hangers","Watch the Product Video            Plenty of Space to Hang a Family Wash  Austral's Foldaway 45 rotary clothesline is a folding head rotary clothes hoist beautifully finished in either Beige or Heritage Green.  Even though the Foldaway 45 is compact, you still get a large 45 metres of line space, big enough for a full family wash.  If you want the advantage of a rotary hoist, but dont want to lose your yard, then the Austral Foldaway 45 is the clothesline for you.&nbsp;  Installation Note:&nbsp;A core hole is only required when installing into existing concrete, e.g. a pathway. Not required in the ground(grass/soil).  To watch video on YouTube, click the following link:&nbsp;Austral Foldaway 45 Rotary Clothesline      &nbsp;            //           Customer Video Reviews  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","https://track.commissionfactory.com.au/p/10604/1718695","http://www.lifestyleclotheslines.com.au/austral-foldaway-45-rotary-clothesline/","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695.jpg","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@50x50.jpg","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@100x100.jpg","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@120x120.jpg","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@200x200.jpg","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@300x300.jpg","http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718695@400x400.jpg","309.9000 AUD","Austral","FA45GR"
```

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets try the trivial (and "not good enough") solution that just adds a double quote to each field (including those that already have double quotes! Which isn't what you want)

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*)/"\1"/g'
```

Great, the first part looks for sequences with no commas in them, the second part adds double quotes around them, the final 'g' means doing it more than once per line

This will turn

```
abc,345, some words ,"some text","text,with,commas"
```

into
    "abc","345"," some words ",""some text"",""text","with","commas""

A few things to note:

- it correctly surrounds "some words" with space between them, BUT also surrounds the initial and final spaces. I assume that's OK but if not it can be fixed
- If the field already had quotes, it will be quoted again, which is BAD. Needs to be fixed
- if the field already had quotes AND the inner text had commas (which shouldn't be considered field separators) these commas are also quoted. This too needs to be fixed

So we want to match two different regexps - either there was a quoted string or a field with no commas:

```
sed -r 's/([^,"]*|"[^"]*")/"\1"/g'
```

The result would now be

```
"abc","345"," some words ",""some text"",""text,with,commas""
```

As you can see, we have a double quote on the originally quoted text. This we will have to remove with a second sed command:

```
sed -r 's/([^,"]*|"[^"]*")/"\1"/g' | sed 's/""/"/g'
```

Which results in

```
"abc","345"," some words ","some text","text,with,commas"
```

YAY!

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just tested your sed syntax however it doesn't appear to provide the desired outcome, I don't know if I'm missing something here, still getting to grips with all of this :)

Comment: if you would like to take a look at one of the original files please use the following to get the CSV `wget --trust-server-names --header="Content-Type: text/csv" -O EXAMPLE_IN.csv --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.205 Safari/534.16" 'http://dashboard.commissionfactory.com.au/Affiliate/Creatives/DataFeeds/jPSA4dbg17SY7svvjeSX5Jf1iO@b5JXshOfY@ovjzeKj4PGivuyn5qqxrLDr86GysLTj$bTyoKaj77Pltfmh9dvnkOCS4MHzjvTSlK6Dfg==/'`

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 24: Unmatched ( or \(` is the output from my Ubuntu CLI

Comment: Tried to get the file. I got a file named "EXAMPLE_IN.csv", but it was empty :(

Comment: Oh, I found a bug! I forgot to copy the second paranthesys here :( will fix in a couple of mins -- edit: fixed!

Comment: I've uploaded the CSV to a non-authed server [link]http://www.timdunkley.com/EXAMPLE_IN.csv

Comment: hhmm, we're getting closer, but still not quite there, if I run `sed -r 's/([^,"]*|"[^"]*")/"\1"/g' EXAMPLE_IN.csv` it displays correctly (without the double quotes at the beginning & end of the line), when combining both regex's into the sed syntax it appears to do nothing? :(

Comment: Ok, found the problem. Your file was created in Windows, so the "end of line" is... not compatible with Linux. See, Windows puts 2 chars at a new line: \r followed by \n. Linux used only \n. So this incompatability breaks you. We need to first remove the \r from your file. Try this: `cat EXAMPLE_IN.csv | tr -d '\r' | sed -r 's/([^,"]*|"[^"]*")/"\1"/g'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34095/discussion-between-cluracan-and-tim-dunkley)

Comment: I have noticed when running the `sed` statement on some CSV files that have empty values in a column:  **Example Input:**  `headerA,headerB,headerC,headerD,headerE`  
`value1,value 2,"value, 3",,value5`  **Example Output:**  
`"headerA","headerB","headerC","headerD","headerE"`  
`"value1","value 2","value, 3",","value5"` In column `"headerD"`, where `value 4` would be if it where _not_ **NULL** the output is `"` where it should be  `""` to ensure the field is correctly enclosed by `"`  I'm not sure if the `sed` statement can be modified to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want every line in a file to begin and end with a double quote.  If so this should work:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' filename
```

Comment: apologies, not every line, every *column" in the CSV to be enclosed in "

Answer (score 0):

Try this [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution. It's superior to my previous [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), because now I use a parser that handles those commas inside fields correctly. It's neccesary the module `Text::CSV_XS` to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

die qq|Usage: perl $0 <csv-file>\n| unless @ARGV == 1;

open my $fh, '<', shift or die qq|ERROR: Could not open input file\n|;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( {
        always_quote => 1,
} );

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
        $csv->print( *STDOUT, $row );
        print "\n";
}
$csv->eof;
close $fh;
```

Comment: @TimDunkley: Please, give more info. Any error? No modification at all? Some rows work but no all of them? How about if you try with a small part of your whole file?

Comment: @TimDunkley: Ah, ok. Rows that fail is because they have commas inside fields. It's too more complex. This `awk` program doesn't handle that case. It's neccesary to switch to a language with a CSV parser. I will try to fix it.

Comment: @TimDunkley: I've edited the answer to use a CSV parser instead. Also I had to change the language, being `perl` now.

Comment: I've updated the original post, for some reason the perl Text::CSV_XS seems to be causing issues with my existing script

Comment: @TimDunkley: `.convert.pl` is this `perl` script? I don't understand your whole script but I think you should look into the line where you assign value to `_header_columns` variable. There you transform the header and remove leading double quote (with `sed`) but not the trailing one.

Comment: @birie yes convert.pl is your script. My script is only looking CSV's in a location, however the CSV needs to be correctly formatted

Comment: @TimDunkley: In last edit you wrote that found trailing double quotes in the SQL table. Are those extra quotes present after running the `perl` script? I don't think so, and in that case the problem is in any point after running the `perl` script, not inside it.

Comment: @birie thanks for your help also, your parser works fine when running the CSV through `tr '\r\n' '\n' < CSV_IN_FILE.csv > CSV_OUT_FILE.csv` to fix the line return first. I have gone with @cluracan solution as it's easier to keep with the same interpreter.